# Linking Azure HDInsight spark application to a Azure EventHub using Java code

Tags: java, azure, spark-streaming, azure-eventhub, azure-hdinsight

How do I write a code to read messages from 1 EventHub to another after some processing in Azure HDInsight spark cluster application using JAVA code ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an exact sample for what you need however a Databricks Spark cluster should not be so different than an HDI Spark cluster to setup. Look at this sample and see if you can move it to HDI - https://lenadroid.github.io/posts/connecting-spark-and-eventhubs.html